# How do I use magic in multiplayer mode?

Tags: god-of-war-ascension

In multiplayer mode, the player can choose which magic ability to use, but it's not obvious why it doesn't always work when the player presses R2. What's the secret to using magic in multiplayer mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem counter-intuitive, but you do not start with a full magic bar. To use magic, you must find a blue magic well and walk over it. This will give you 50 magic, which is denoted by the blue bar underneath your health bar.  You can do this again, for a maximum of 100 magic, which makes the magic bar turn a lighter color. At this point, you can't take magic from a well since you are full, but your spell will now work when you press the button.

Note also that some magic spells only require 50 magic, where others require 100.